# django cms + zinnia / display zinnia entry in cms page

Tags: django-cms, zinnia

I got Django CMS and Zinnia set up, working fine. Now I would like to display the content of the latest Zinnia post on the front page.

```
{% get_recent_entries 1 %}
```

Adding the above to my template will display the title of the post linked to the content page. But I would like the content itself to be displayed right away, and I wouldn't care about the link to the full entry. Is there a way to do this in the template and if so, how? Or do I need to write my own code?

This is my first Django project, so be easy on me, ok =)